# How to Install Tensorflow on Google Coral Dev Board?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

How to install Tensorflow on Coral Dev?

Getting errors following [this](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm) on Coral Dev board (one of them):

Error Message: `compile.sh` not found.

Please, give me some additional instruction, thanks.

Comment: Please provide detailed explanation on what errors are you getting.

Answer (score 3):

It is really not going to be possible to help if you don't give details on what you've done or what errors you ran into while trying to install it. 
However, since the objective is to install tensorflow on the board, you can just do this using this pre-built package:

```
$ wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.0.0/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_aarch64.whl
$ sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev libhdf5-dev python3-h5py
$ sudo pip3 install tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_aarch64.whl
```

Also, please note that using the full tensorflow on the board isn't going to gain any performance from the TPU.

[Edit] Apologies, forgot to credit [lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm) repo for the prebuilt package!

Comment: I haven't tested, but its worth noting that updated packages by the author are [available here](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases).